# Custom checkbox in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I created custom radio input

My code:

```css
.options input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.options input[type="radio"]:checked + .poll-field img {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url("https://example.com/img/checkmark.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-8 options">
    <label for="p2_1_1">
        <input type="radio" name="p2_1" value="1" id="p2_1_1"/>
            <div class="poll-field">
                <span class="poll-text">1</span>
                <img src="{{ asset('img/check_empty.png') }}" class="poll-img-check">
            </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

It works on Chrome, Firefox, even on IE, but not on Safari (13.0.4).
On Safari I can mark only the first option. When I try to select a different number than "1" - the checkmark didn't appear.
Checkmarks only appear when I open web inspector, pick ANY element and unmark and mark some CSS rule (in any CSS class).

[image: Safari sample poll]

Have someone similar problem or have any idea to solve this?

Comment: try to avoid `display: none` and `-webkit-appearance` on the input, but use instead something like `position:absolute; clip:rect(0,0,0,0)`. Also check the `for` attribute (you can avoid it, since the input is nested)

Answer (score 0):

I added this and it fixed all

```
.options input[type="radio"]:checked + .poll-field {
    background-color: white;
}
```